# How to call a Model in unassociated controller/view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

How do I call a model in a separate controller/view?

I.E. I have a User model, and in my Static controller, in the home method/view, I would like to call @user for a signup form.  When I do this it throws a no method error.  Is there a way around this?

I am using devise.

**Static Controller**

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @user = User.new
  end
end
```

**Home.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :trackable, :validatable

  protected 
    def password_required? 
         false 
    end 

end
```

**The following solution does not work.  I get a**

```
NOMETHODERROR in STATIC#HOME
undefined method `users_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fe888125480>:0x007fe8881247d8>
```

Any ideas as to why this is??

Comment: do you have a resources :users in your routes.rb file?  That's what creates these helper paths

Comment: wow.  I had devise_for :users. Added resources for users and works beautifully.  Its the little things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you are getting seems to indicate that there is no helper method for users_path

That helper method will be available if you add the following line to your config/routes.rb  file.  The entries in the config/routes.rb file are what create these helper paths.

```
resources :users
```

Here is a link to check out as well.
 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

In your action in the Static Controller you just need to create a User instance

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController
   def home
      @user = User.new
   end
end
```

Now in, static/home.html.erb

```
<%= @user.inspect %>
```

will work, so you can use it with `simple_form` etc.

If you are writing the user sign up from scratch on purpose thats cool, otherwise you might want to check out `devise` gem.

Comment: <%= @user.inspect %> Does show up now, but the simple_form throws an error.